# Xcode getting Cocoapod framework error when compiling on ARM MacBook

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to integrate Admob into my app, and the code is good, but there is a problem when I try to run the app in the simulator.

I'm using the new MacBook Air M1, BigSur, Xcode 12.2.

I get the following errors:

> in /Users/octomac/Documents/CryptoCalc/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEExperiment_3e0573efa7b433360f767304cef16d18.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/octomac/Documents/CryptoCalc/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture arm64

Also:

> warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in '/Users/octomac/Documents/CryptoCalc/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework GoogleMobileAds framework ios-armv7_arm64 ios-i386_x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (arm64).

I've looked through Google to no avail.

Comment: Remove the architecture from the Build Settings.

Comment: It now outputs a new error: /Users/octomac/Documents/CryptoCalc/CryptoCalc.xcodeproj The linked framework 'Pods_CryptoCalc.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.

Comment: What's your architecture set in project settings? Can you see simulators in your scheme or a mac?

Comment: https://imgur.com/JeP2KQV this is what I have in project settings. I can see iPod, iPhone simulators - I'm using iPhone 12 simulator (as I use it in real life).

Comment: I just tried to run it on my physical iPhone 12 and it works. It just throws out the error with simulators.

Comment: Im having the same issue, builds fine for simulator on my intel mac but on my m1 macbook pro it cant with the same issue, the error goes away if I exclude arm64 from debug and release but then I have another issue with a Module that doesn't have x86_64, only arm64. Gonna suck building the ui and having to deploy to physical device to see changes.